# How to dynamically create Auto-Renewable Subscription

Tags: swift, xcode, subscription

Our app is something like news app where user can subscribe to some author. List of authors comes from server therefore hardcode every subscription for each author is not the way to go.

In iOS YouTube app you can create an auto-renewable subscription for a channel, and it looks like YouTube has created a special subscription group for every author on the platform.

So, Is that possible to somehow implement what I want with In-App Purchases?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to create a subscription dynamically. Dynamic Auto-Renewable Subscriptions creation (and dynamic in-app purchase creation in general) is not possible.

The only possible option is to create a number of subscription groups, let's say 5 groups representing each author.